# Is OpenCV_2.4.2_binary_pack_armv7a source code open

Tags: android, opencv

Is it possible to get OpenCV_2.4.2_binary_pack_armv7a source code. Is it open source? I don't want to install the OpenCV_2.4.2_binary_pack_armv7a.apk separately in my device. I want to include OpenCV_2.4.2_binary_pack_armv7a in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the source code is open, but this is a wrong question. First of all read about so-called [static initialization](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization), this must be exactly what you want.

You should also distinguish between OpenCV Manager and OpenCV library packages, see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/android/service/doc/Intro.html).

Comment: Also if you want to check the source code, start here: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Working_with_OpenCV_git_repository